# Is it possible to create Dynamic SQL statements purely in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, dynamic-sql, information-schema, sqlite-3.33, sqlite3

A lot of modern RDBMS have a feature called `Dynamic SQL` ([MS SQL Server, for example](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/)) which allows you to build your SQL statements in strings and then execute that string of SQL.

Does such a feature exist **purely** in SQLite?

I'm aware I can build my statements dynamically using a functional language that uses SQLite as a database. But that's not applicable to the problem I'm trying to solve because the dynamic statements I'm trying to build are based off of relational logic and involve `sqlite_master` and `PRAGMA`, and translating that logic into a functional language makes trying to solve this problem not worth it.

For all intents and purposes, I have the flexibility to use any version of SQLite to solve this problem.

Comment: You admit yourself that this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please ask a question about the actual problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

SQLite is designed as a small, embedded database to be accessed from a 'real' programming language. Dynamic SQL is not needed for its intended purposes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept your answer. The very problem I'm trying to solve with Dynamic SQL actually proves there is a use case for it in SQLite, but unfortunately I can't go into too many details for proprietary reasons. Similarly why my question appears to be an XY problem although that classification is a little subjective. Sometimes the problem is the question itself and nothing more (though in this case that's because there is nothing more that can be provided.) Anyways thanks for the info!

Comment: CREATE TABLE my_table(fname,lname);
INSERT INTO my_table VALUES('joe','bloggs');
.output dynamic.sql
WITH x(i) AS (values('fname'),('lname')) SELECT PRINTF('SELECT %s FROM my_table',GROUP_CONCAT(i)) FROM x ;
.output
.read dynamic.sql

Comment: (Not very scalable - but you can use the features of the sqlite3 command line to generate your dynamic SQL - write that to a file and read it back in and run it)

Comment: (see also the '.once' command - avoid the need for the zero arg '.output' to stop output)